# Adding Custom Code Under Product Description in WooCommerce Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

Trying to add some custom code under the product description but can't seem to find a hook to do this. woocommerce_product_after_tabs works well but it shows on every tab. Is there a specific hook for underneath the product description, if not how do I show only when the description tab is active?

Comment: Here you can see all hooks https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Comment: @MartinMirchev I saw that already but there doesn't seem to be a hook for under the description and above the related products. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Have you tried `add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'your_function', 15);` ? 15 is positioned between 10 (product tab) and 20 (related products).

Comment: If you look up the content-single-product.php template as @Zaim mention you will see hook woocommerce_after_single_product_summary and since tabs are priority 10 , upsell 15 and related 20 go with 11-14 priority to be sure.

Comment: I solved my problem by just adding it to the description and forcing it to always be on the last line so it doesn't interfere with the actual description. The woocommerce_after_single_product_summary didn't work for me as it would show on all tabs, it worked the same as woocommerce_product_after_tabs. Thank you for your input though.